# UMP Test and UMVUE when there are nuisance parameters

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, exponential-family, weibull-distribution, umvue

Consider $X_1,...,X_n \sim Weibull(\theta, c)$ where $c>0$ is unknown. Several textbook examples consider when $c$ is known, but here, we consider when $c$ is unknown. Suppose now we wanted to find the UMVUE for $\theta$ and the UMP test, testing $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0$ and $H_a: \theta > \theta_0$.

Normally when $c$ is known, a complete sufficient statistic is $T = \sum X_i^c$, so by Lehmann-Sheffe, we can find some function of $T$ such that E(g(T)) is unbiased. However, this will depend on $c$ as $g(T)$ is a function of $T$ and $T$ involves $c$ - which is unknown, thus cannot be used as an estimator.

Similarly, we can also show that $\sum X_i^c > k$ (reject) is a UMP test by MLR and Karlin-Rubin however, again, this rejection rule depends knowledge of $c$ which is unknown, so we can't use that as a test.

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this nuisance parameter $c$ in finding UMVUE and in UMP testing.

Perhaps in this case, a UMP test fails to exist and the UMVUE fails to exist, but I am not sure how to prove that.

Comment: When $c$ is unknown, this is no longer an exponential family, hence it has no fixed dimension sufficient statistic.

Comment: @Xi'an and that is true because we now cannot have a statistic $T(X) = \sum X_i^c$ since it also a function of a parameter now.